# Distribute the value of a cell over multiple cells untill the remaining value is 0

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a solution to automatically distribute the value of a cell (C3 till C10) based on the number of months (B7 till B10).

Anyone who can help me out with this formula?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First, you can make a helper row as showed in image attached starting with number 1.

Then apply below formula to **cell(E5)** and drag across the range.

Formula: "=IF($B5>=E$3,$C5/$B5,0)"

[Related Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P2bT.png)

Thanks 
Abhinav

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate it. Could you help me out with a formula to identify the amount of months between two different kind of 'dates'. see the second image I shared in this topic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: =MONTH(DATEVALUE(C3&"1"))-MONTH(C2)+1

Answer (score 1):

Type the following formula into cell E7:

```
= IF(COLUMN()-COLUMN($E7)+1<=$B7,$C7/$B7,0)
```

Then drag this cell over and then down as far as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

For second part, to calculate amount of months you can add formula in cell("C4") as:

=MONTH(DATEVALUE(C3&"1"))-MONTH(C2)+1

[image: Amount Months Calculation]

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the quick follow up!

Comment: Found myself in a new challenge. What if the month is in 2018 or 2019. Then the amount of months is not calculated correctly:( Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add one new row after"B3" to enter year. So cell("B4") value = "Year". cell("B5") value = 2018 (example) and new formula at cell("C5") = "=MONTH(DATEVALUE(C3&"1"&", "&C4)-MONTH(C2)+1)"